# Sorting Ruby array of array items by length evenly

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, parallel-processing

In Ruby, how can I sort an array such that its items (also arrays) are arranged by their length size, but not just simply sorted by ascending/descending in length.

I'd like to make the array items distributed evenly so that there are some items that contain large number of objects intermixed with smaller arrays.

For example, I have this array with array items that contain the number of objects shown in the `comment`. I've broken them in chunks for clarity and calculated their total size (see motivation below).

```rb
[
  # chunk 1, inner total length 5
  [{...}], # 2
  [{...}], # 1
  [{...}], # 1
  [{...}], # 1
  # chunk 2, inner total length 11
  [{...}], # 2
  [{...}], # 2
  [{...}], # 3
  [{...}], # 4
  # chunk 3, inner total length 9
  [{...}], # 3
  [{...}], # 3
  [{...}], # 1
  [{...}], # 2
  # chunk 4, inner total length 15
  [{...}], # 4
  [{...}], # 3
  [{...}], # 4
  [{...}], # 4
]
```

I'd like to arrange the array so that it looks more like the below. Note: that this example has them ordered smallest to largest (1..4), but that is not necessary. I'd just like to have them chunked so that the inner array cumulative length are comparable.

```rb
[
  # chunk 1, inner total length 10
  [{...}], # 1
  [{...}], # 2
  [{...}], # 3
  [{...}], # 4
  # chunk 2, inner total length 10
  [{...}], # 1
  [{...}], # 2
  [{...}], # 3
  [{...}], # 4
  # chunk 3, inner total length 10
  [{...}], # 1
  [{...}], # 2
  [{...}], # 3
  [{...}], # 4
  # chunk 4, inner total length 10
  [{...}], # 1
  [{...}], # 2
  [{...}], # 3
  [{...}], # 4
]
```

My motivation for this is to slice up the outer array so I can process the inner arrays in parallel. I don't want one of the parallel processes to get a slice of small chunks, and another process get a slice of really large chunks.

Note: I know that I'll have 4 parallel processes so that may help inform how to arrange the chunks in the array. Thanks!

Comment: Very interesting question although I am concerned that any gain you might receive from processing each distributed chunk in parallel will be out weighed by the initial sorting algorithm required for the distribution.

Comment: What about data that can't be evenly sorted? Say I have 4 arrays of lengths 1, 2, 4, and 4. They can't be evenly grouped.

Comment: Also, depending on your parameters, (and per my above comment, assuming a solution exists at all) this problem is NP-Complete. Consider the case where you want to organize a large data set into only two chunks. Bam, you've got the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). This is to say that for certain inputs, calculating this can take a very long time.

Comment: @engineersmnky, That's a good point. The processing on these items is already pretty expensive which leads me to weigh the cost of an upfront sort.

Comment: As a suggestion, a heuristic approach might be better. You could dechunk all the arrays and sort by array length. Then iterate over the block giving items with `index % 4 == 0` to the first process, `index % 4 == 1` to the second, `index % 4 == 2` to the third, `index % 4 == 3` to the fourth. This wouldn't give a perfect solution but would be _roughly_ correct. It has the benefit of being much simpler, and the initial sorting much faster.

Comment: You could also avoid pre-chunking by just setting up four workers, then having the master issue each worker a job; when a worker finishes the job, it gets the next available job. It means some workers might do several big jobs, while some other do more smaller ones, and in the end it is kind of even (up to the length of one job's difference). This also works when job length is not predictable from the input. For example, the [`parallel`](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) gem can do it automatically for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm I would use to get a roughly even distribution of size, per my comment on OP:

```rb
unchunked_data = [
  [{...}],
  [{...}],
  [{...}],
  [{...}],
  [{...}],
  [{...}],
  [{...}],
  [{...}]
]

sorted_data = unchunked_data.sort_by(&:size)
grouped_data = sorted_data.each_with_index.group_by { |_, index| index % 4 }

grouped_data.each do |process_index, data|
  # each_with_index would put data in an array with its index in sorted_data. Calling map(&:first) removes that index.
  data_without_index = data.map(&:first)
  send_data_to_process(process_index, data_without_index)
end
```

If the data is as it appears in OP's example, this results in a perfect distribution.

---

Per discussion in the comments, you can get back all the data in single array, as formatted in the original but grouped with this method, by doing:

```rb
grouped_data.values.flatten(1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Glyoko, I'm leaning towards this solution. One thing is I don't want my array necessarily grouped (or nested in a third array), can you return it back to the form of your `unchunked_data` ( one array of arrays)? Also, I'm inclined to use `grouped_data.map` instead of the `grouped_data.each`, as i'm going to process it outside of that block that is stripping those pesky index numbers (per your each_with_index comment).

Comment: None of this code changes `unchunked_data` in place, so you can still manipulate it after the fact with it in the same order it start as.

Comment: As for `grouped_data`, I suppose you can use map, but be aware that `grouped_data` is hash not an array. It's keys would be the `process_index`s, (0, 1, 2, 3), and the values would be their respective sorted and grouped chunks. (Don't forget that the comment about using `map(&:first)` on the values would still apply for this too.)

Comment: Per you first comment, I just meant I'm hoping to have the result of all this be an array of arrays in the distributed order (which matches the structure of the original `unchunked_data`). For your second comment, and related... I don't want a hash and so that's why I'll be using .map which'll return `[ [ [ ],... ] ]`, but I'd rather get `[[],...]` if that makes sense. I'm going to be doing something like `each_slice(grouped_data.size / 4)` with the result.

Comment: Note that this method won't necessarily give a more even spread than my answer; it depends entirely on the input... For example, suppose the original array sizes are: `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]`. My answer will chunk these as: `[[1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [3, 3], [3, 4]]` - i.e. total sizes of `[7, 7, 6, 7]`; whereas this answer will chunk them as: `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]` - i.e. total sizes of [6, 6, 6, 9]`. I'm not certain which algorithm is most likely to give the best spread.

Comment: @mfink in that case you can do something like `grouped_data.values.flatten(1)`. @TomLord That's correct. The problem is actually NP-complete, so both of our answers are just "best guesses". One may be better than the other depending on the data.

Comment: I ended up going with this solution as it tended to make more even distribution for the dataset I was working on. Also readability in general. I would like to remove the `&:first` cleanup step, but I'll save that for another day. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a "perfect" solution, but here's an approach that's not too computationally heavy/complex:

1. Sum up the length of all inner-arrays:

```
total_count = original_list.map(&:count).inject(:+)
```

2. Determine how many items you want to put in each parallel process (in your case, **4** processes):

```
chunk_size = total_count / 4
```

3. Now, here's the harder part: The algorithm. I'm going to keep this very simple, and just step through each item in the array, and ["chunk"](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) until it's reached the `chunk_size`:

```
current_chunk_size = 0

original_list.chunk_while do |inner_array|
  current_chunk_size += inner_array.count
  current_chunk_size = 0 if current_chunk_size >= chunk_size
  current_chunk_size > 0
end
```

You could achieve similar logic with methods like `slice_after`, if you prefer.

Using this algorithm against your original example:

```
[
  # chunk 1, inner total length 5
  [{...}], # 2
  [{...}], # 1
  [{...}], # 1
  [{...}], # 1
  # chunk 2, inner total length 11
  [{...}], # 2
  [{...}], # 2
  [{...}], # 3
  [{...}], # 4
  # chunk 3, inner total length 9
  [{...}], # 3
  [{...}], # 3
  [{...}], # 1
  [{...}], # 2
  # chunk 4, inner total length 15
  [{...}], # 4
  [{...}], # 3
  [{...}], # 4
  [{...}], # 4
]
```

Yields the result:

```
[
  # chunk 1, inner total length 12
  [{...}], # 2
  [{...}], # 1
  [{...}], # 1
  [{...}], # 1
  [{...}], # 2
  [{...}], # 2
  [{...}], # 3

  # chunk 2, inner total length 10
  [{...}], # 4
  [{...}], # 3
  [{...}], # 3

  # chunk 3, inner total length 10
  [{...}], # 1
  [{...}], # 2
  [{...}], # 4
  [{...}], # 3

  # chunk 4, inner total length 8
  [{...}], # 4
  [{...}], # 4
]
```

...Pretty close.

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach and will test it out. Close enough is good :)

Comment: Tom, I’m having trouble following your calculations. For one, shouldn’t `original_list.chunk_while` be `original_list.flatten(1).chunk_while`?  You may want to run your code against the example in my answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Your data assumes the input may be nested deeply, but the original question (which admittedly is invalid syntax, so somewhat ambiguous!) didn't state this. You used: `[[[0,1], [2], [3], [4]], ...]`, but I'm assuming it's: `[[1, 2, 3, 4], ...]`

Comment: I see. I'm afraid I still don't follow. It would be helpful if you could include a simple example. Note `chunk_while` returns an enumerator, so I expect you need `end.to_a`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another heuristic.<sup>1</sup> I'll explain the procedure shortly. We are given:

```
arr = [[[0,1],         [2],        [3],           [4]],
       [[5,6],         [7,8],      [9,10,11],     [12,13,14,15]],
       [[16,17,18],    [19,20,21], [22],          [23,24]],
       [[25,26,27,28], [29,30,31], [32,33,34,35], [36,37,38,39]]
      ]

nbr_groups = 4
```

Let's first flatten one level and sort the resulting arrays by size.

```
sorted = arr.flatten(1).sort_by(&:size)
  #=> [[2], [3], [4], [22], [0, 1], [5, 6], [7, 8], [23, 24], [9, 10, 11],
  #    [16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21], [29, 30, 31], [12, 13, 14, 15],
  #    [25, 26, 27, 28], [32, 33, 34, 35], [36, 37, 38, 39]]
```

We need to group elements of `sorted` into an array `result` containing `nbr_groups` arrays. This will be done by "sweeping" the elements of `sorted` into `result`. The sweeping consists of `nbr_groups` forward assignments  alternating with the same number of reverse assignments.

Now create an enumerator.

```
a = nbr_groups.times.to_a
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3] 
idx = [*a, *a.reverse].cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0]:cycle>
```

The heuristic I suggest begins by assigning the first `nbr_groups` elements of `sorted` to `result`, such that the first element of `sorted` is assigned to the first element of `result`, the second element of `sorted` is assigned to the second element of `result`, and so one. The next `nbr_group` elements of `sorted` are similarly assigned to `result`, but this time in reverse order: the `nbr_groups+1`'th element of `sorted` is assigned to the last element of `result`, the `nbr_groups+2`'th element of `sorted` is assigned to the penultimate element of `result`, and so on. These alternating assignments are continued until all elements of `sorted` have been assigned.

```
result = sorted.each_with_object(Array.new(nbr_groups) { [] }) do |a,arr| 
  arr[idx.next] << a
end
  #=> [[[2], [23, 24], [9, 10, 11], [36, 37, 38, 39]],
  #    [[3], [7, 8], [16, 17, 18], [32, 33, 34, 35]],
  #    [[4], [5, 6], [19, 20, 21], [25, 26, 27, 28]],
  #    [[22], [0, 1], [29, 30, 31], [12, 13, 14, 15]]]
```

Now let's see how evenly these assignments were made:

```
result.map { |a| a.sum(&:size) }
  #=> [10, 10, 10, 10]
```

This result brought a smile to my face. That all elements of `result` are the same size is of course purely coincidental.

<sup>1. As @glyoko pointed out in a comment, the problem is NP-complete, so one must resort to using a heuristic for all but the smallest problems.</sup>

Comment: Very neat, but I'm not sure I understand how the "sweep" helps. Just using `idx = a.cycle` seems to work just as well.

Comment: @Glyko, suppose `sorted = [[0], [1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8,9]]` and `nbr_groups = 2`. By sweeping, `result #=> [[[0], [6,7,8,9]], [[1,2], [3,4,5]]`, `result.map { |a| a.sum(&:size) } #=> [5,5]`. With `idx.cycle`, `result #=> [[[0], [3,4,5]], [[1,2],  [6,7,8,9]]`, `result.map { |a| a.sum(&:size) } #=> [4,6]`. With `idx.cycle`, `result.map { |a| a.sum(&:size) }` will tend to be non-increasing and be non-increasing if `sorted % nbr_groups #=> 0`.

Comment: Cool, that makes sense. Doing every other pass backwards tends to even out the distribution.